# Groovy mixin unable to see its properties when invokeMethod is involved

Tags: groovy, mixins

I'm seeing something I can't explain with Groovy (1.8) mixins when I drop an `invokeMethod` method onto one of the mixin classes.

The following test demonstrates this effect:

```
 1: import java.net.Socket
 2:
 3: import org.junit.Test
 4: import static org.junit.Assert.*
 5: 
 6: class MixinPropertyTest {
 7:     static class Foo {
 8:         def message
 9:        
10:         Object invokeMethod(String name, args) {
11:             if (name != "println") {
12:                 println "invokeMethod sees ${message}"
13:                 println "invoking ${name}"
14:             }
15:             def metaMethod = metaClass.getMetaMethod(name, args)
16:             metaMethod?.invoke(this, args)
17:         }
18:         
19:         String message() {
20:             message
21:         }
22:     }
23:     
24:     @Mixin(Foo)
25:     static class Bar {
26:     }
27:     
28:     @Test
29:     void test() {
30:         assertEquals 'hello', new Bar(message: 'hello').message()
31:     }
32: }
```

This test fails with the following output:

```
invokeMethod sees hello
invoking message
```

However, if I clip out `invokeMethod`, it passes.  What about the `invokeMethod` being there causes this to stop woring?

EDIT:  If I set breakpoints at lines 15 and 20, I see `this` as `MixinPropertyTest$Foo (id=43)` and `MixinPropertyTest$Foo (id=75)`, respectively. It looks as though the `Foo` instance I'm interacting with changes during the course of the `MetaMethod.invoke` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to puzzle this out with the debugger.

Because `invokeMethod()` was using `this` (an instance of `Foo`) rather than the object owning that mixin, `MixinInMetaClass.getMixinInstance()` under the covers decides to create a new instance of `Foo`.  (It caches mixin instances based on the outer object and it thinks that I'm looking for a mixin instance of `Foo` within an instance of `Foo`.)

I appear able to work around this by noticing when invokeMethod is called on an instance of an OwnedMetaClass:

```
class Foo {
    // ...
    Object invokeMethod(String name, args) {
        def target = this
        if (metaClass instanceof OwnedMetaClass) {
            target = metaClass.owner
        }
        MetaMethod metaMethod = target.metaClass.getMetaMethod(name, args)
        metaMethod?.invoke(target, args)
    }
    // ...
}
```

This seems like something that should be handled automatically by Groovy.  Requiring classes to have extra code in `invokeMethod` to enable being used as a mixin seems un-Groovy.

Comment: Ha, I just rifled through Groovy source code and found what you were seeing in the debugger. I agree it's not very Groovy to handle this. Perhaps a bug should be opened?

Answer (score 1):

Using `invokeMethod` intercepts ***all method and property calls*** according to [Using invokeMethod and getProperty](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+invokeMethod+and+getPropertyhttp://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+invokeMethod+and+getProperty). If you want it to pass through to `message()`, you should add an if clause to check if the method name is "message" or change `invokeMethod` to `methodMissing`.

**EDIT:**

Since you're trying to intercept the call, I think the problem may be that the forward `invoke` is not getting the correct metaMethod. That is, since you're using `metaClass` from `this` you're going to get the `MixinInstanceMetaMethod` because `this.metaClass` refers to the `MixedInMetaClass`. Given that you have that `MetaMethod` it should be invoked on the metaClass owner (which should be the `Bar`).

The following code should work:

```
import org.junit.Test
import static org.junit.Assert.*

class MixinPropertyTest {
    static class Foo {
        def message

        def invokeMethod(String name, args) {
            System.out.println "invokeMethod sees ${message}"
            System.out.println "invoking ${name}"

            def metaMethod = this.metaClass.getMetaMethod(name, args)
            metaMethod?.invoke(this.metaClass.owner, args)
        }

        String message() {
            message
        }
    }

    @Mixin(Foo)
    static class Bar {
    }

    @Test
    void test() {
        assertEquals 'hello', new Bar(message: 'hello').message()
    }
}
```

Futher clarification: I think because the `this` you're passing into the metaMethod.invoke is already the mixin instance, the reason why `this` changes is because the metaMethod is a `MixinInstanceMetaMethod` which tries to look up the mixin instance. If it's not found it creates a new mixin instance, which is why the reference to `this` is different from the `invokeMethod` to the `message` method.

[This line in the Groovy source](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/metaclass/MixinInstanceMetaMethod.java#L53) shows that calling `invoke` looks up the mixin instance.

This line in the source shows the creation of a new mixin instance: https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/reflection/MixinInMetaClass.java#L68

Comment: Intercepting existing methods is entirely intentional, so using `methodMissing()` or somehow excluding the call to `message()` would not be an appropriate solution. Using a debugger, I can see that the call to `message()` properly dispatches, but for whatever reason `this` in `message()` ends up being a different `Foo` instance than it is within `invokeMethod()`, which confuses me.